# dynamic sd card file path Android

Tags: android, file, path, external

Please help me out. We are developing an app in which we provide some files(videos/texts) in sd card to read them through the app. But the problem is that , sd card path in different devices are different. How to make sd card path unique so as to hit the target file in sd card through any Android device. Please supply code.

Answer (score 0):

use  this to get external directory path for any Android device

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```